# New not allocating enough memory?

Tags: c++, new-operator, memcpy, packets

Well, I'm taking packets straight off the wire and extracting TCP streams from them.

In the short, this means stripping off the various headers (eg, eth->IP->TCP->stream data).

In the function that is called when I've finally gotten through all the headers, I am experiencing a strange error.

```
    /*Meta is a pointer to the IP header, pkt is a pointer to the TCP header*/
    virtual const u_char* processPacket(const u_char* pkt, const u_char* meta) {
        //Extract IP info from meta.
        iphdr* metaHdr = (iphdr*)meta;
        //Form TCP header from the current offset, hdr.
        const tcphdr* hdr = (const tcphdr*)pkt;

        //Do pointer math to figure out the size of the stream data.
        u_int32_t len = ntohs(metaHdr->tot_len) - metaHdr->ihl*4 - hdr->doff*4;
        if(len > 0)
        {
            //Store TCP stream data in a queue, mapped to it's IP source.
            TCPStream* stream = new TCPStream();
            stream->seqNumber = ntohl(hdr->seq);
            stream->streamData = new u_char(len);
            //memcpy(stream->streamData, offset(pkt), len);
            for(u_int32_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                printf("k%i-%i",len, i); //Used to figure out when the segfault occurs.
                stream->streamData[i] = offset(pkt)[i]; //Offset returns a pointer to the data under the TCP header
            }

            //streams[metaHdr->saddr].push(stream);
        }

        return offset(pkt);
    };
```

TCP stream is simply a `u_int32_t` and a `u_char*` pointing to a copy of the packet's data.
So, when I was using memcpy it segfaulted.
Obviously, either my pointers were invalid, or I was messing up my length.

In this particular packet's case, the length of the data is 1380 bytes (confirmed by Wireshark), so len is correctly computed.

Ok, so I must have my pointers messed up (but not NULL).  I did the following experiment:

```
stream->streamData[0] = offset(pkt)[0]; //Works
stream->streamData[0] = offset(pkt)[len]; //Works, odd.
stream->streamData[len] = offset(pkt)[0]; //Fails, scary
stream->streamData[len] = offset(pkt)[len]; //Fails
```

So, I segfault when dereferencing too far into streamData (index 1236 to be specific)!
But streamData is instantiated as:

```
stream->streamData = new u_char(len);
```

I start iterating through streamData at i=0, so I'm not skipping a bunch of my data.
streamData is `u_char*` and `offset(pkt)` is `u_char*` so I'm not messing up my types.

This fails at a particular packet, after successfully iterating through 3000+ other packets.  The dump file is 27 megs, and I've got 4 gigs of ram, so I don't think I'm running out or anything...  So I'm forced to conclude that new is not allocating enough memory, but why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
stream->streamData = new u_char(len);
```

This allocates a single character, intialized to `len`.

To allocate an array, use:

```
stream->streamData = new u_char[len];
```

And where-ever you deallocate it:

```
delete [] stream->streamData;
```

**Edit:**

```
stream->streamData[len] = offset(pkt)[0]; //Fails, scary
```

That would be undefined behavior even if the array was allocated correctly. Valid indexes to access are 0 to `len` *not inclusive*.

Comment: duh, must be all that java programming in school; and fail on me for not len-1'ing.  

stupid stupid me.

Comment: And it works, all packets are successfully iterated and stripped of their headers where appropriate.